# How to add a default third parameter `$absolute` to the `route()` function?

Tags: php, laravel, routes, frameworks

```
string route(string $name, mixed $parameters = [], bool $absolute = true)
```

I need to add `$absolute = false` as the **default** for all the website,
I tried to override the urlGenerator class but I didn't succeed.

can someone help?

thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You can't redeclare existing function. The only option is to declare your own function and use it:

```php
function myroute($name, $parameters = [], $absolute = false) {
  return route($name, $parameters, $absolute);
}
```